# Contact form 7 em post personalizado

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

Tenho formulários de contato feitos com o plugin contact form 7 dentro do meu site, só que os formulários de contato só funcionam em páginas, dentro de posts não funcionam.

Na página de contatos ele envia corretamente e mostra a mensagem de enviado:

[image: pagina de contatos deu ok]

Na *single* do portfólio envia o e-mail, mas o *loader* ficar infinitamente rodando e não exibe mensagem de enviado:

[image: single portfolio erro]

O erro que ocorre:

[image: mensagem de erro]

Debugando JS pelo Chrome vejo que ele fica nessa função em loop a vida  toda, só que só acontece isso quando o form tá dentro do *single* do post na página não dá erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Tem algum plugin ou código rodando só no `single.php`, talvez se comparar o html seja fácil descobrir.

Answer (score 2):

A [FAQ oficial possui uma entrada para este problema](http://contactform7.com/faq/the-spinning-arrow-icon-shows-up-once-i-submit-a-form/). A causa mais frequente é algum plugin ou tema causando incompatibilidades, por exemplo quando o plugin ou tema adiciona versões diferentes de bibliotecas usadas pelo plugin.

[Esta entrada](http://kb.cf7skins.com/contact-form-7-email-issues/#pluginconflict) na base de conhecimentos do plugin relata exatamente o problema que você está tendo e sugere [um artigo](http://kb.cf7skins.com/javascript-conflict-problems/) com dicas de como encontrar a causa real do problema.

Basicamente a primeira dica é trocar o tema e ver se funciona. Se ainda não funcionar, desabilite todos os plugins exceto o Contact Form 7. Se isso resolver o problema, habilite novamente um a um até descobrir qual é a causa.

Só para você ter uma ideia, [este tópico de suporte](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/send-confirmation-not-showed-loading-icon-forever) relata a experiência de um usuário com o mesmo problema. No fim, ele descobriu que o plugin [WP Facebook Open Graph protocol](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-facebook-open-graph-protocol/) era a causa.

O problema pode ocorrer porque você pode ter widgets diferentes nos posts *single* ou porque algum plugin ou tema faz distinção usando `is_singular()` ou alguma outra função interna do Wordpress que verifica o tipo de página sendo exibida.

Resolver definitivamente o problema é outra história. Depois de identificar qual é o plugin ou tema culpado, você teria que identificar exatamente a raiz do problema.

O caso mais comum, como já citei, é ter diferentes versões de uma mesma biblioteca como jQuery. Você também pode olhar no do fonte HTML e procurar por esse tipo de problema comum.

Depois de identificada a raiz do problema, tem que ver se existe uma solução fácil. No caso de bibliotecas duplicadas, o primeiro passo é remover uma e ver se mesmo assim tudo continua funcionando. Se não funcionar, algum dos plugins vai ter que ser ajustado para funcionar com a versão diferente.

Verifique também se todos os plugins estão devidamente atualizados. Versões antigas podem ter incompatibilidade com bibliotecas mais novas.

Answer (score 0):

Thiago, para debugar isso vc vai ter que desabilitar todos os outros plugins. Então, se funcionar vc vai ativando um por um até descobrir qual plugin esta dando conflito. Se mesmo desativando os plugins continuar com o problema, então o Contact Form 7 esta dando conflito com alguma função JavaScript do seu tema. Se não conseguir resolver então muda para outro plugin de form. Ninja Forms e Caldera são bons e gratuítos tb. Boa sorte.